# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Id'

Tags: python, series

I am trying to create a malware classifier and I am experiencing the error

```
 AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Id. Not sure of the error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File"C:/Users/Afiqmatters/PycharmProjects/MajorProject/feature_extraction.py", line 23, in <module>
rids = [mids.loc[i].Id for i in rchoice]
 File "C:\Users\Afiqmatters\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2744, in __getattr__
return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Id'
```

Here is the codes I have up to the error.

```
rs = Random()
rs.seed(1)

trainLabels = pd.read_csv('trainLabels.csv')
#print trainLabels

fids = []

opd = pd.DataFrame()

for label in range(1,10):
    mids = trainLabels[trainLabels.Class == label]
    mids = mids.reset_index(drop=True)
#print mids
rchoice = [rs.randint(0, len(mids) - 1) for i in range(10)]
print len
#print rchoice
rids = [mids.loc[i].Id for i in rchoice]
```

The error happens at   rids = [mids.loc[i].Id for i in rchoice] and I am not sure of the error.

A sample of what is stored in the trainLabels.csv

```
Id                                   Class
0A32eTdBKayjCWhZqDOQ                    2
```

Answer (score 0):

`mids.loc[i]` in this context is a "Series" object which is detailed [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html)

This object type does not have an attribute `Series.Id`, so that's why you're seeing this error.

Did you mean to call the built-in function [id( )](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) on the object?

`rids = [id(mids.loc[i]) for i in rchoice]`